# Enhance clustering with evaluation function

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, k-means

My goal is to partition a dataset (`X`) in distinct clusters. I'm using k-means to be able to pick the center of each cluster assuming all other datapoints behave the same.

Only for the feature selection phase, I have a evaluation dataset (`y`) which precicely describes the quality of the clusters obtained (by computing the actual distance between given datapoints
from X, which does not necessarily correspond to distances in the input dataset `X`; given as a distance matrix for each pair of samples from `X`).

My input dataset has a lot of data available in terms of features from which I can choose (not in terms of actual samples); all continous but varying in scale. How can I determine important features and scale them properly to improve my clustering algorithm?

Simple feature elimination by removing features not improving the k-means was my first step, but the runtime is awful even for this simple example.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are facing a metric learning problem. Here is a survey on the topic: https://people.bu.edu/bkulis/pubs/ftml_metric_learning.pdf

In particular, the [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) library for Python provides algorithms to [learn Mahanalobis distances](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/metric-learn/introduction.html#mahalanobis-distances) over the labelled part of your data ([supervised metric learning](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/metric-learn/supervised.html)), which you can use to transform your complete dataset to a lower dimensional space before applying k-means. If the dimensionality reduction is significant, so will be the performance improvement of k-means which likely spends a lot of time calculating the distances between your large feature vectors.

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what i was looking for ::)